# Swift: how to take AnyObject.Type as a parameter?

Tags: swift, swift5

there is a code below:

```
let cls = NSClassFromString("UIView") as? UIView.Type
```

I want extract this code to be a **function** :

```
func ClassFromString(_ className: String, _ classType: AnyClass) -> AnyClass?{
   return NSClassFromString("UIView") as? classType   // it is error
}
```

but it is not working. how to do?

Comment: What is the point of your code if you need to supply the class type? Then you might as well do `var view: UIView`directly, what am I missing here?

Comment: This code smells pretty *objective-c-ish*. I guess there is a *swiftier* way

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
func getClassFromString<T>(_ cName: String, cType: T) -> T.Type {
    return NSClassFromString(cName) as? T.self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic function like this

```
func classFromString<T>(_ className: String, _ classType: T) -> T? {
    return NSClassFromString(className) as? T
}
```

And use it as follows

```
if let cls = classFromString("UIView", UIView.self) {
   let view = cls.init()
}
```